# GIven Unencrypted and encrypted data (AES-GCM) both, is it possible to calculate the Chiper key of AES-GCM

Tags: aes

Sorry for a simple curiosity,
Given Unencrypted and encrypted data (AES-GCM) both, is it possible to calculate the Chiper key of AES-GCM ?

Answer (score 2):

No, assuming AES is secure. That would be a known-plaintext attack.